# How to add new/custom module to magento admin?

Tags: magento-1.9

In here I have not experience with building a custom modules to magento admin panel. So I need to know useful links or tips to build that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the some refernce:

- [excellencemagentoblog](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/26/admin-part1-series-magento-admin-forms-grids-controllers-tabs/)
- [tutsplus.com](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-payment-method-module-in-magento-part-two--cms-23539)
- [inchoo](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/)

As per as,my thought , excellencemagentoblog is best.

Comment: Really helpful. Great.